# Facebook messenger.com URL redirect does not open messenger app

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I have a redirect in place for my site which when access, redirects the user to the Facebook messenger app. It's a vanity URL http://www.example.com/talktome that's redirected to (say) https://www.messenger.com/t/meetErnest. If I access the link on desktop it opens the messenger app in the browser but when I try to access on mobile, it prompts me to download the messenger app. I already have the messenger app downloaded on my phone. How can I make it work so that when I access the vanity URL on mobile it opens the messenger app?

Thanks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a m.me link instead:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/m-me-links